# Django: Force create index on ForeignKey fields when db's `supports_foreign_keys=False`

Tags: django

I'm trying to use Django (v4.1.3) with Planet Scale's DB which is MySQL compliant with the relevent exception of not supporting foreign keys.

For this, they provide a [Django DB driver](https://github.com/lnxpy/django-psdb-engine) which subs class the MySQL DB feature class

```py
from django.db.backends.mysql.features import \
    DatabaseFeatures as MysqlBaseDatabaseFeatures

class DatabaseFeatures(MysqlBaseDatabaseFeatures):
    supports_foreign_keys = False
```

Given this, when I generate migrations and apply them on my local MySQL server, I don't see any foreign keys being created as expected. However, I also don't see keys being created but I still want the keys.

For example with the MySQL driver, when I run `SHOW CREATE app_user_groups` (from `django.contrib.auth` package) I see the following key:

```
CREATE TABLE `auth_group_permissions` (
  ...
  KEY `auth_group_permissio_permission_id_84c5c92e_fk_auth_perm` (`permission_id`),
)
```

But with the Planet Scale driver (`supports_foreign_keys = False`), Django doesn't create an key/index.

I know in my models, I can explicitly define keys but I don't find this ideal. In addition, I don't have control over models from other Django apps like `django.contrib.auth` and many other 3rd party ones.

What can I do to make Django create keys on `django.db.models.ForeignKey` despite support for foreign keys being off.

Comment: I don't think this is an easy task without submitting a PR (and get it merged) to the Django project as you will at least want to patch `add_field` and `table_sql` methods in `django.db.backends.base.schema.py`. I believe the short term solution would be to add the `db_index` arguments for your own fields, and manually index the tables created by built-in apps.